# Why is my lisp function giving me this output?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I am writing a function that will take a list from a user and will flatten this list into one simplified list. The function seems to only return the first item on the list and not the rest? Any suggestions on why it is doing this?

Example:

```
> (flatten '(a () b (c d))
(a b c d)
```

This is what I have so far

```
(defun flatten (list)
(cond 
    ((null list)t) 
        (list (first list) (rest list))
        (t(append (flatten (first list))
                (flatten (rest list)))
    (t(cons (first list (flatten (rest list))))))))
```

The output it is giving

```
> (flatten '(a () b (c d)))
(NIL B (C D))
```

Comment: `(list (first list))` - because you're telling it to only return the first element?

Comment: @melpomene I just realized what I had done, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Now your code says: If `(null list)` (i.e. if `list` is empty/nil), return `t`. Otherwise, if `list` (i.e. if list is non-empty/not nil), get the first element and ignore it, then get the `rest` (all but the first element) and return that. Your remaining code is irrelevant because one of the first two conditions is always true.

Comment: @melpomene how could I tell the condition to check if the first thing is a list and if it is to to then go down to the append function. Then if it's not a list "else" go to the cons.

Comment: @melpomene, excuse my previous comment just to clarify, how can I write the condition to tell it to check and see if the first element is a list? If the first element is a list to then go to the `append` function. If the element doesn't satisfy those conditions then go to the "else" which would be the `cons`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are editing the original question with updated code, which makes it a moving target. Currently, your code is the following one, after I ask Emacs to indent it with <kbd>M-q</kbd> (lisp-mode):

```
(defun flatten (list)
  (cond 
    ((null list)t) 
    (list (first list) (rest list))
    (t (append (flatten (first list))
               (flatten (rest list)))
       (t (cons (first list (flatten (rest list))))))))
;;  ^^^ Something is not good, why is the clause indented?
```

Parentheses structure the code for the computer, whereas indentation is a way to print this structure for human readers. This redundancy allows you to detect problems in source code when one does not match the other. Here, the `(t cons)` is not a cond clause, it is nested inside the previous clause.

Second, as said in comments, `cond` will go to the first clause for which the test succeeds. If you wrote `(cond (t X) ...)`, nothing in the `...` part would change the meaning of the code, which always returns `X`. In your code, you test as follows:

1. `(null list)` tests whether `list` is `eq` to `nil`.
2. `list` **does not** test whether `list` is a list. There is a predicate named `listp` to detect that. When you put `list` alone like this, you are asking whether `list` is a generalized true value, which is necessarily true when you previously ruled out `nil` (the previous clause).
3. The default clause `(t ...)` has no way to be used, because the previous test cannot fail.

Here is a skeleton:

```
(defun flatten (form)
  (cond
    ((null list) ...)
    ((consp list) ...)
    (t ...)))
```

Instead of `consp` you could write `listp`, but note that by definition a list is either `nil` or a cons cell, so `consp` is a little more explicit and does not overlap with a test for `nil`. Note also that I always test against the type of form, which is a pattern that is often found. That's why you might prefer to use [`typecase`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tpcase.htm).

Comment: thank you after playing around with the skeleton you provided me I was able to figure it out